# Docker unable to locate file, even with correct path given

Tags: docker, centos, vcf-variant-call-format

I'm running a long docker command

```
docker exec -t -i 9f5865473027 cloudgene run imputationserver@1.4.1 --files /illumina/runs/con/chrX_impute/ALL.chrX.PAR2.phase3_v5.shapeit2_mvncall_integrated.noSingleton.genotypes.vcf.gz --refpanel apps@1000g-phase-3-v5@2.0.0 --conf /etc/hadoop/conf --population AFR --mode qconly --output /illumina/runs/con/chrX_impute
```

but this is giving an error

```
Error: Input Files (<a href="http://www.1000genomes.org/wiki/Analysis/Variant%20Call%20Format/vcf-variant-call-format-version-41" target="_blank">VCF</a>): file '/illumina/runs/con/chrX_impute/ALL.chrX.PAR2.phase3_v5.shapeit2_mvncall_integrated.noSingleton.genotypes.vcf.gz' not found.
```

why isn't docker finding a file that is given with an absolute path (even with a relative path)?  How can I make docker find this file?

even when I do

`docker exec -it 9f5865473027 ls /illumina/runs/con/chrX_impute/ALL.chrX.PAR2.phase3_v5.shapeit2_mvncall_integrated.noSingleton.genotypes.vcf.gz`

I still get `ls: cannot access /illumina/runs/con/chrX_impute/ALL.chrX.PAR2.phase3_v5.shapeit2_mvncall_integrated.noSingleton.genotypes.vcf.gz: No such file or directory`

when I do `docker exec -it 9f5865473027 ls .` it seems to be in `/` or the absolute top directory, but using this information and entering the file name without `/` thus `docker exec -it 9f5865473027 ls illumina/runs/con/chrX_impute/ALL.chrX.PAR2.phase3_v5.shapeit2_mvncall_integrated.noSingleton.genotypes.vcf.gz`

Docker is still unable to find the file :(

I can see higher directories via docker's `ls` but the directory that I'm in is `docker exec -it 9f5865473027 ls illumina/runs/con/chrX_impute` mysteriously shows as empty (which it isn't)

Comment: I think this error is more related to your application instead of Docker. Since, container is running and you can easily confirm whether this file is present inside the container or not by running `docker exec -it <container-id> ls /path/to/file`

Comment: @oli `docker exec -it 9f5865473027 ls illumina/runs/con/chrX_impute/ALL.chrX.PAR2.phase3_v5.shapeit2_mvncall_integrated.noSingleton.genotypes.vcf.gz` still gives the same error :/

Comment: Okay, this means file doesn't exist inside container.

Comment: @oli how can I ensure that a file exists inside a container?

Comment: Are you copying the file inside container? or do you've any volume sharing between host and container? if not then you've to put file inside container first (through dockerfile instructions or using docker cp_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem is to *copy* the file to the container.  Each "container" seems to act as if it is a separate computer.

All I had to do is

```
docker cp ALL.chrX.PAR2.phase3_v5.shapeit2_mvncall_integrated.noSingleton.genotypes.vcf.gz 9f5865473027:/illumina/runs/con/chrX_impute/
```

and then the file shows up as

```
docker exec -it 9f5865473027 ls illumina/runs/con/chrX_impute
ALL.chrX.PAR2.phase3_v5.shapeit2_mvncall_integrated.noSingleton.genotypes.vcf.gz
```

Comment: Great you solved it yourself. One tip though, to avoid doing this everytime create a Dockefile with desired instructions to start your container with pre-defined configurations and requirements.